# Have 3 domain names and across 2 vm. How do I manage them?

Tags: apache, virtualhost, ubuntu-server, self-hosting, esxi

I want to host multiple websites of 2 Virtual Machines which one should I port forward to? Also how would I make one domain go to the different ip?
I am hosting this of a server running ESXi with 2 VMs that have website both are running Ubuntu Server 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here.

1. How to distribute load into two servers
2. How to host multiple websites

To address the first problem, you are required to setup [load balancer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)), it can be easily achieved by using [apache module `mod_proxy_balancer`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html).

Example of balancer configuration:

```
Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
<Proxy "balancer://mycluster">
    BalancerMember "http://192.168.1.50:80" route=1
    BalancerMember "http://192.168.1.51:80" route=2
    ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
</Proxy>
ProxyPass "/test" "balancer://mycluster"
ProxyPassReverse "/test" "balancer://mycluster"
```

To the second problem, you can check [Name-based Virtual Host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html).

Example of virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # This first-listed virtual host is also the default for *:80
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com 
    DocumentRoot "/www/domain"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName other.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/www/otherdomain"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: They have different internal ip addresses for example one website is on the vm with 192.168.1.10 and the other one is no 192.168.1.11 how would i control it between them?

Comment: you should make a server to be a load balancer, ie domain name points to load balancer server. and two servers require to setup virtual host, serve different `DocumentRoot` for different domains

Comment: How would I set up the load balance would? Should that be a different VM. Is there a tutorial of how to do this?

Comment: it is fully documented in `mod_proxy_balancer` and many tutorial about load balancing with Apache